# How to get live api credentials for paypal?

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, credentials

I am using ubercart for drupal site.In payment methods I have checked

```
PayPal Express Checkout 
PayPal Website Payments Standard 
Credit card (includes PayPal Website Payments Pro)
```

all these options. For sandbox account in paypal I entered test account credentials and  its working fine. Now I need to change to Live, but i don't know how to get credentials for live account.

This is the status of paypal developer page [image]

how do I get live API credentials such as (API username,API password,Signature)??

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking at REST API Credentials which has Client,Secret Id for  REST API calls
To just get Classic API Credentials:

-log in to your PayPal Account
-click on Profile->My selling Tools->API access
-click on Request API-Credentials
-Option 1 PayPal API,click on Set up PayPal API credentials and permissions
-option 2, click on Request API credentials
-choose Request API signature and click on Agree and Submit
-Your Credentials are displayed to you

--or --

Just click this [**link**](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_get-api-signature&generic-flow=true) and enter your paypal login credentials.

Comment: dat link. best SO answer to date